# javascript count down to show days?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript countdown that will show seconds. I need to know how I can show days in the counter instead of second.

i.e. 1 day, 2 hours left.

this is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var MAX_COUNTER = 1000;
var counter = null;
var counter_interval = null;

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter = MAX_COUNTER;
}

function stopCounter() {
    window.clearInterval(counter_interval);
    deleteCookie('counter');
}

function updateCounter() {
    var msg = '';
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter -= 1;
        msg = counter;
        setCookie('counter', counter, 1);
    }
    else {
        counter = MAX_COUNTER;

    }
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}

function startCounter() {
    stopCounter();
    counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
}

function init() {
    counter = getCookie('counter');
    if (!counter) {
        resetCounter();
    }
    startCounter();
}

init();
</script>
```

at the moment it only shows seconds and it will restart itself once it hits 0.

Comment: you need to convert seconds into hours, mins and days. try http://jsfiddle.net/h2DEr/

Comment: since it worked, I am putting an answer to the question so that you may close this question.

Comment: @vdua, the only problem is now that it will Start from 24 hours (which is what I want) but after a few minutes, it will change itself to 15 minutes left!!!  any suggestions?

Comment: what i understood is that you want counter to start from 24 hours remaining and then it should move to 15 mins (in some amount of time) and then it should decrease by 1 sec every second. 
First to start with 24 hours make `MAX_COUNTER = 3600*24` and where you are decreasing the counter initially decrease it by large amount say 1 hour and when counter's value becomes 15*60 decrease it by 1. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @vdua, sorry, maybe I explained it badly. I don't need it to jump to 15 minutes. when it starts from 24 hours, it needs to carry on counting down for the whole 24 hours (no jumping to 15 minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/h2DEr/1/

function updateCounter() {
    var msg = '';
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter -= 1;
        msg = convertSecondsToDays(counter); 
        setCookie('counter', counter, 1);
    }
    else {
        counter = MAX_COUNTER;
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that converts seconds to days

```
function convertSecondsToDays(sec) {
  var days, hours,rem,mins,secs;
  days =  parseInt(sec/(24*3600));
  rem = sec - days*3600
  hours = parseInt(rem/3600);
  rem = rem - hours*3600;
  mins = parseInt(rem/60);
  secs = rem - mins*60;
  return days +" days " + hours +" hours "+mins + " mins "+ secs + " seconds";
}
```

**update:** after @sanya_zol's answer and comments from David Smith

since setInterval is not supposed to run every second, you need to change your strategy a little bit. I have modified the fiddle for that as well

1. Set MAX_COUNTER to a value when you want it to expire.
2. instead of decreasing the counter by -1, check the current time, subtract it from the expiry date and display it.

   ```
     EXPIRY_SECONDS = 24*60*60;
     MAX_COUNTER = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/(1000)) + EXPIRY_SECONDS;

     function updateCounter() {
        var msg = '',curTime = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);

        if (curTime < MAX_COUNTER) {
           msg = convertSecondsToDays(MAX_COUNTER- curTime);
           setCookie('counter', MAX_COUNTER- curTime, 1);
        }
        else {
           MAX_COUNTER = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000) + EXPIRY_SECONDS;
        }

        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (el) {
          el.innerHTML = msg
        }
      }
   ```

Comment: Although I selected this as answer but this still not working correctly. the count down will reset itself on page refresh which is was not happening on my own code and it shouldn't happen.

Comment: I never thought that was the use case. Have modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h2DEr/5/

Comment: Thank you very much. and this will reset itself once it reaches 0 ?

Comment: The fiddle works in this way. tell me whether it is what you want or not. when a person opens the fiddle, a cookie is set which expires after 24 hours and stores that time and a timer starts which calculates the remaining time and displays it. When a person revisits the fiddle the value from the cookie is read which tells the expiry time (which must be less than 24 hours). When the timer expires it resets it to expire after 24 hours. Hope I have explained what I have done.

Comment: You should take the latest fiddle, the previous one had a little code missing which was not resetting the timer perfectly. The cookie was not getting reset. My apologies for the same. http://jsfiddle.net/h2DEr/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
```

The 1000 is value in milliseconds so how many milliseconds are there in a day?

```
counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000*60*60*24);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm an absolute noob in javascript and I am not entirely sure how to use the code you've given me. any chance you could explain it a bit please?

Comment: I did replace your code with my code and when I replaced it, nothing happens. the counter stops working....

Comment: It counts one day at the time so you have to wait until tomorrow to see if it works or not.

Comment: Just realized the code I submitted doesn't work at all, vdua's answer would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

addition to vdua's answer:

Your code is really badly written.

It uses setInterval which counter is not precise (moreover, it have very, very bad precision) - so **your counter's second will be equal to 1.05-1.2 real seconds** (difference between real time and counter **will accumulate**).

You should check system time (via **(new Date).getTime()** ) every time at lower intervals (like 100 ms) to get precise counter.