# Javascript seconds countdown

Tags: javascript

I have been trying for hours to make a javascript function that will take an input time in seconds and provide a countdown. For some reason it just refuses to count down after the first second and I can't figure out why not.

Here is my HTML:

```
<span style="display:none;" id="unixtime_coming_0">600</span><span onload='timer()' id="timer_coming_0"></span>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
setInterval(function timer() {
  var count = document.getElementById("unixtime_coming_0").innerHTML;
  count = count - 1;
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
  var days = Math.floor(count / 86400);
  var hours = Math.floor(count / 3600) % 24;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) % 60;
  var seconds = count % 60;
  document.getElementById("timer_coming_0").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; // watch for spelling
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a named function doesn't return anything. You have to define it outside of `setInterval`:

```
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    var unixtime = document.getElementById("unixtime_coming_0");
    var count = parseInt(unixtime.innerHTML, 10);
    unixtime.innerHTML = count - 1;

    if (count < 1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var days = Math.floor(count / 86400);
    var hours = Math.floor(count / 3600) % 24;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) % 60;
    var seconds = count % 60;

    document.getElementById("timer_coming_0").innerHTML= days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; // watch for spelling
}
```

I'd get rid of the `setInterval` completely. Just call `timer` via `setTimeout` inside of `timer` itself.

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of `setInterval` when implementing a countdown, something that strikes me as needing a very precise interval? Using `setTimeout` in the function itself means that the 1-second interval only begins after the function has run, so the true interval will be longer.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: I though I had some reason for getting rid of it, but now I forgot and can't really see why it's a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is being reset to 600 on every loop. Just move its declaration outside of the function, like so:

```
var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("unixtime_coming_0").innerHTML, 10);
setInterval(function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
[...]
```

Comment: I like your use of `parseInt` (it's a good habit). Wouldn't `count` otherwise be cast to a number when 1 is subtracted from it? Is there any justification other than good habit?

Comment: @RickViscomi Yes it does, so in this example it is unnecessary. But I would still try to make sure `count` is always a number, so that later additions to the code don't run into unexpected problems, and also to give the compiler an easier time optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

For accurate count down you need to use new Date().getTime(). Please have a look at this answer for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/15635372/1523245